# Observable collection is nothing despite ByRef

Tags: wpf, vb.net, observable, ref

I'm calling a Method from my viewmodel in my model `_pdfViewer` which has an ObservableCollection as parameter (ByRef) like this:

```
_pdfModel.LoadAnnos(AnnotationList) 'AnnotationList is the Collection
```

In this method I assign values to the collection:

```
Public Sub LoadAnnos(ByRef annotationList As ObservableCollection(Of PdfMarkupAnnotationDataWrapper), pdfViewer As PdfViewerControl)
  annotationList = XMLSerialization.Deserialize()
  For Each anno In annotationList
     AddAnnotationsToPdf(pdfViewer, anno)
  Next
   End Sub
```

Now the collection has some values and is NOT nothing.

The line `AddAnnotationsToPdf(pdfViewer, anno)` triggers an event in my ViewModel (from where i called the method `LoadAnnos`). 
If I use the collection `AnnotationList` now in this event, it is nothing.

Here is the event:

```
   Public Sub PdfViewerTextMarkupAnnotationCreating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PdfTextMarkupAnnotationCreatingEventArgs)
  _pdfModel.AddAnnotationsToList(AnnotationList, e)
  If AnnotationList IsNot Nothing Then   'AnnotationList is nothing even tough it wasn't in LoadAnnos
     XMLSerialization.Serialize(AnnotationList)
  End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Show that event

Comment: It is quite brittle, LoadAnnos could easily use another variable named AnnotationList.  Given that it is called in code that is far removed from the model.  A dependency injection framework tends to be necessary to avoid these kind of bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. What should I change to avoid such bugs? And I don't get the reason why the collection is nothing in the event, would be really nice if somebody can explain it to me. :)

Comment: What is the argument after `annotationList = XMLSerialization.Deserialize()`, `annotationList`  field should have a collection of `PdfMarkupAnnotationDataWrapper`...

Comment: `XMLSerialization.Deserialize()` returns a collection of `PdfMarkupAnnotationDataWrapper`

Comment: Make sure you build with `Option Strict On`.  VB will try to be helpful and perform conversions for you, even with `ByRef` arguments (typically resulting in copy-in followed by copy-out) which can make it very difficult to reason about what your code is actually doing, especially when properties are involved.